# How the AWK works when 2 files are interchanged in a script while comparing

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` script, when the file names are interchanged I could see 2 different result. I'm curious to know here how awk writes output to the console with different result in each case

File 1:

```
abc bca cdb

abc few bre

bbc bba cdb

cbc frw bte
```

File 2:

```
abc bca cdb

gbc fiw bpe

bbc bca cdb

cbc frw bte
```

Script :

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1$2$3]++;next};!(($1$2$3) in a)' **file1 file2**
```

Output :

```
gbc fiw bpe

bbc bca cdb
```

Script:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1$2$3]++;next};!(($1$2$3) in a)' **file2 file1**
```

Output:

```
abc few bre

bbc bba cdb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first command gives you the lines in `file2` that can't be found in `file1` while the second command gives you the lines in `file1` that can't be found in `file2`.

For the given data, the code is equivalent to

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$0]++; next } !($0 in a)'
```

where `a` is an array that has been keyed with the lines from the *first* file. The condition at the end says "print this line (from the second file) if it's not found in the first file".